# Shading where all normals point towards each light source automatically

Tags: materials, shaders, normals, npr

I don't really know how to describe this better, but I've seen someone use this for their NPR shader and it looks like that method stopped working in 2.93, see this post: https://twitter.com/Moeark/status/1386968029083291648

Basically this shading looks like all normals are pointing to a light source without having to specify which object to point to, and on a material level, so you could blend this shading with diffuse for example. You can kind of replicate this effect with Normal Edit Modifier, but that affects normals for everything and only works for one target.

[image: Replication using Normal Edit]

You can also see how it worked in a video made by the same person: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CAtNoegUYJM

Any ideas on how to replicate this?